# Mouse optical sensor doesn't work but clicks are fine, only on one computer

Tags: usb, drivers, mouse

I have been using a logitech g502 for 5 years now and it was working fine until last month. Since then the optical sensor has stopped responding but the clicks and the scrollwheel are working normally. The mouse works perfectly when I plug it into another computer, whatever the OS.

The PC where it doesn't work is on Windows 10.

I have tried many solution I could find on the internet but none worked,

I tried :

- plug the mouse on another usb slot,
- unplug everything but my mouse,
- uninstall the driver of my mouse and restart my computer,
- update my mouse driver,
- force installing .sys files in my windows 32,
- contacting Logitech and followed their advices but none worked,
- uninstalling Logitech G Hub and it's residue
- cleaning my mouse's optical sensor
- reinstalled windows 10

I don't know what could be the source of the problem and I have to say I need help.

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the mouse's optical sensor with a lens cleaner?

Comment: No I have not, I'll will give it a try but the problem is not coming from here, because the mouse works perfectly on all my other computer, 2 of them also being on windows 10.